# Brown line in back of shrimp

Tags: fish, shrimp

What could be a brown line in the back of an already peeled shrimp?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is the gastrointestinal tract of the shrimp. It is commonly called a *vein* or *sand vein*. It is often removed, but [this is not required](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/10612/60) since it is not harmful and is mostly tasteless.

To devein a shrimp  you would make a shallow cut from head to tail and then wipe or rinse out the vein under running water.

Comment: I would think choosing not to remove it depends on the size of the shrimp.  I really wouldn't want to eat the vein from a large shrimp.

Comment: It would certainly be unappetizing.